# How to explain a software bug to a child

Tags: software, debugging, release-management, bug, software-updates

When I buy a house or a car, the product is already completely ready. It's very seldom that an error will be noticed later by the customer.
In software engineering, on the other hand, errors (bugs) are normal and occur frequently. Even in production bugs can be found, so that software receives updates regularly.

Suppose, I'm talking to a child. I explain that fixing errors, even in productive software, is an important part of my daily routine. He might think, that I'm a bad programmer, who delivers flawed products.

How to make it clear, that bugs are normal?
Is there a simple analogy from the real world?

Comment: see [How do I explain ${something} to ${someone}?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6630/31260)

Comment: I think this is offtopic, but honestly except for very simple things, almost any product can have a bug in a similar way to a software bug. I mean, for extreme cases, a non well built house might collapse or the brake system of a car may fail. I think it's easy to link with that.

Comment: _"When I buy a house or a car, [..] it's very seldom that an error will be noticed later by the customer."_ I think that is really not a correct statement. Pretty much everyone who didn't build their own house tends to find some shoddy craftmanship, and there is a significant recurring pattern with finding hidden damage in a car that proves it was in a serious crash before - even if the seller claims it hasn't been.

Comment: I knew a guy who had a house built for him, and unfortunately someone drilled a hole through a water pipe. What did they do to fix it? The wrapped a plastic bag around the bit with the hole, with a really good knot. Some time later the wall started to go black and mouldy. Sure, no bugs when you buy a house.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> When I buy a house or a car, the product is already completely ready. It's very seldom that an error will be noticed later by the customer.

That’s a wrong assumption. In all the countries I have lived so far, there is a mandatory requirement to subscribe a construction insurance to cover bugs discovered up to 10 years after construction.  Because a house is a complex system. Moreover Courts have plenty of examples of malfunctions.

The quality of cars is higher nowadays. But I got a car a couple of years ago that I had to stop and restart on very cold days, for the engine to work well. Again, garages are full of such cases.

> How to make it clear, that bugs are normal?
> Is there a simple analogy from the real world?

Very simple: making software is like constructing a castle of legos for someone. At first one need to agree how the castle should look like. And sometimes there are misunderstandings, that we notice only when the castle is build. That’s a castle-bug.  Sometimes the  castle is so complex that it does not work in the end: a wall breaks, a door can’t be opened because there is no room to get to it and so on. That’s also bugs.

Of course we make everything possible to avoid the bugs. But when it happens, it’s the occasion to make it better so that everybody is happy on the end. And that’s what makes software as funny as building lego castles.

*(P.S: Some kids prefer castles, some prefer zoos, houses or spaceships. Chose the subject according to the demonstrated interests of the kid. And I have no lego stocks: any other construction set, including the sandbox will do)*

Comment: Not to forget about the bugs in the software of most modern cars ;-)

Comment: I would distinguish bugs from poor specification. Your castle example sounds more like poor specification.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede I did not mention "specification" because it's narrowing down the issue and raises new questions. You can have a good specification but later discover that there is a case that is not covered.  Perhaps it existed already when specs were written. Perhaps it's completely new. People would nevertheless call it "bug".  A lot of bugs also occur independently of the specs, due to misunderstanding between developers or between different versions of yourself, or misunderstanding of the problem.  This is why I insisted on misunderstandings. But you're right poorly crafted code exists.

Comment: You didn't mention "specification" by name, but you described it. "At first one need to agree how the castle should look like. And sometimes there are misunderstandings, that we notice only when the castle is build." That is NOT a bug.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede What's your definition of bug?  Many definitions (see [3 examples here](https://test.io/blog/what-defines-a-software-bug/)) see it as a **deviation from expectation** and not as a deviation from specification.  There is hence a lot of room for interpretation and I can ensure you that court rooms are full of parties accusing each other of bugs when in the end it's only a set of misunderstandings.  Not to speak about the case where the upfront agreement is just a vague outline (far from a spec), that is then refined iteratively with stories during the construction process ;-)

Comment: @Christophe Maybe I'm not making myself clear, because I'd say all three of the definitions in your link agree with me. In particular, note that the third definition specifies an expectation "which may not be specified but is reasonable." For example, it's probably not in a spec that an "OK" button should affirm a choice. That's commonly assumed, and there are many UX assumptions like that. If an "OK" button cancels an action, that could be considered a bug. But If the button is blue and the client wanted green, whether it's a bug depends entirely on whether green is in the spec.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede thank you for this excellent example and opportunity to clarify. Customer expects buttons to be green, the button color in his own windows theme. Dev hardcoded blue but didn’t notice any issue because own theme uses blue. Customer claims it’s a bug because apps are expected to comply with windows theme. Dev claims the bug is in the specs because they should be clear on such expectations. Moreover Dev offered a fixed price based on assumption of fixed colors. But customer cannot use the product because a coworker has a disability that requires another theme with high contrast…

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede … in the end bit parties acted in good faith and delivered their fair contribution. Misunderstanding happens. The question is: what could both together have done differently to prevent misunderstandings: so there’s a kind of bug in the overall process that let this odd situation happen. Somehow the parties will have to settle, and once the misunderstanding clarified, the question will be who has to pay for the “non-bug” correction. My while point is about this story: there are more than one point of view. and what is a bug for one party may be ok for the other.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede For this reason the subjective use of  “bug” might be counter-productive because puting the responsibility on the other party. Misunderstanding, non-compliance, defect are more neutral and facilitate the dialogue. But thanks for your patience, I’d agree and that you may still disagree. All these detailed explanations in the comments are way too detailed anyway for a child to understand ;-)